# Problem to change the Windows policy of execution in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, angular-cli, policy, executionpolicy

I try to run the command `ng` in a PowerShell, but systems require that the script must be signed.

I try to change my policy of execution.

This is my current configuration `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List:`

```
          Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       AllSigned
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted
```

Then, I run the next command `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted`

The change on the policy it's OK, but appear an error telling **another policy defined in a most especific ambit deny the value.**

And the command `ng` still not running with the error, `\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1` it's not signed digitally.

Can you help me?
Ty everyone

Comment: [_"MachinePolicy. Set by a Group Policy for all users of the computer"_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) -- this is propably what prevents you from changing the policy for the current user. It would make sense that a group policy, which is set by administrators, cannot be overridden by the user. You can try running the script like this: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File $env:AppData\npm\ng.ps1`

Comment: I have tried to run the command, same error.  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Comment: Then you have to ask the admin to make an exception in the group policy for your machine or user.

Comment: And do you know how can I make that exception? Im the admin of the system. Ty for the answer.

Comment: https://4sysops.com/archives/set-powershell-execution-policy-with-group-policy/